# CustomErrors not redirecting to custom page but MVC default error page

Tags: model-view-controller, web-config, custom-errors

I have a new MVC 4.0 solution created from scratch using VS2012 web express and IIS Express.
As the tile says I changed my web.config and added the following in :

```
<customErrors defaultRedirect="Errors/GenericError.html" mode="On">
    <error statusCode="404" redirect="Errors/Error404.html"/>
</customErrors>
```

Basically when I get an exception in my controller the default MVC error.cshtml is showing the error instead of my custom page GenericError.html.

If I go to a URL that doesn't exist, my Error404.html is showing correctly but not for the generic scenario.

Any ideas how I can change this behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you don't have the error attribute in your global filters. In an MVC 4 project you should be able to search for the class `FilterConfig` that was generated for you:

```
public class FilterConfig
{
    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
        filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
    }
}
```

**Update:**

The `HandleErrorAttribute` global filter is for errors that occur in the MVC pipeline, such as errors in your controller as you mention.

The `customErrors` element in the `web.config` is for everything else. The `HandleErrorAttribute` will not honor the value you put in the `defaultRedirect` attribute of `customErrors`.

The `HandleError` filter will look for a shared view which you should have in your generated project `shared\Error.cshtml`. You can point it to a different view by setting a property on the attribute.

For example, let's say we create a new view under `Shared\Errors\CustomError.cshtml`, then you could register the filter like this:

```
filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute(){View = "Errors/CustomError"});
```

Comment: My solution was completly generated from the template so it's there in AppStart/FilterConfig.cs. Otherwise it wouldn't even show the error page in the shared views I guess?

Thi is my FilterConfig.cs:

using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace MyNamespace
{
    public class FilterConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
        {
            filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
        }
    }
}

Comment: Ok, that's exactly the behavior I'm experiencing, so now that you explained this way I can at least grasp the concept. I'll play around with the sugestion you mention regarding using a different view. Thank you so much. Marked it as answered.

Comment: Is there any references to how HandleErrorAttribute is dependent on the MVC pipeline? For example, when the path goes to an non-existing controller, this seems to be catched by the customErrors in web.config, but resolving controllers should be well within the MVC pipeline, right?